# Docker Swarm : docker stack deploy results on untagged images <none>

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile, docker-swarm, docker-registry

I'm deploying some images from my registry into my application server using **docker swarm mode hos**t :

My image in the registry is looking like this (executing `docker images`) :

```
REPOSITORY                                                 TAG                   IMAGE ID            CREATED            SIZE
localhost:5000/myApp                                       G02R00C09_myTag   c1fc2242f9a0        2 hours ago         272MB
```

Under **my docker compose file** , my service looks like this :

```
---
version: '3.4'
services:
  ihm:
    image: myRegistryServer:5000/myApp:G02R00C09_myTag   
    stdin_open: true
    volumes:
    - /opt/logs:/opt/logs
    tty: true
    ports:
      - target: 80
        published: 80
        protocol: tcp
        mode: host
    deploy:
      mode: global
      placement:
        constraints:
          - node.labels.type == abc
    healthcheck:
      disable: true
```

**->** after executing `docker stack deploy` :

i got my stack and my service well running  (when i run `docker stack ls` and `docker service ls` , everything is ok)

**->** but when running `docker images` , i do get my image **but with** `<none>` **tag**:

```
image:  myRegistryServer:5000/myApp      <none>
```

Comment: How did you build the image (command used to build it)? Also try `curl myRegistryServer:5000/v2/myApp/tags/list -v` to see if registry shows the tag you want.

Comment: i ve built it using docker_image module of ansible and it results on successfully tagged image in the registry

Comment: What does `curl` show? That should be it.

Comment: > GET /ihm/tags/list HTTP/1.1
> User-Agent: curl/7.29.0
> Host: myResgitryServer:5000
> Accept: */*
>
< HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found

Comment: Why is your registry not accessbile?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is normal. When using Swarm Stacks, it converts your tag into the SHA256 of that image and downloads that specific ID. This guarantees each node has the same image. If it only depended on the tag, you could potentially re-use the tag in a `docker push`, and it's possible for different nodes to download different images.

You can see the tag used in a `docker service ls` or `docker stack ps <stackname>`

Comment: How do you suggest to proceed for cleaning after a service is removed?

Comment: I assume you're talking about images or volumes? those are the only objects that a service creates but doesn't remove. Check out the `prune` commands like `docker image prune --help` and my example of using a daily task to auto-prune all unused images on all nodes: https://github.com/BretFisher/dogvscat/blob/master/stack-prune.yml