# docker stack deploy results in images with <none> tag and varying image sizes

Tags: docker, docker-swarm, docker-image, docker-stack

I understand from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50152854/docker-swarm-docker-stack-deploy-results-on-untagged-images-none) that it is normal for images to get a `<none>` tag in `docker stack`, but I do not understand why the image size varies from the tagged one. I couldn't find any information regarding this, so I resorted to posting a question on stackoverflow. Can anyone explain this?

```
mysql                         <none>              a8a59477268d        2 weeks ago         445MB
mysql                         8.0                 c01d431b7858        10 months ago       266MB
phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin         <none>              7af57eae1e90        3 weeks ago         163MB
phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin         latest              3405a88394e3        9 months ago        111MB
```

This is the docker-stack.yml file.

```
version: "3"

services:

  server:
    image: "com:latest"
    deploy:
      replicas: 3
      update_config:
        parallelism: 1
        delay: "10s"
        monitor: "10s"
        failure_action: rollback
      resources:
        limits:
          cpus: "0.25"
          memory: 50M
        reservations:
          cpus: "0.25"
          memory: 25M
    ports:
      - "80:80"
    links:
      - db
    networks:
      web:
    restart: always

  db:
    image: "mysql:8.0"
    deploy:
      mode: global
      resources:
        limits:
          cpus: "0.25"
          memory: 100M
        reservations:
          cpus: "0.25"
          memory: 20M
    networks:
      web:
    volumes:
      - db:/var/lib/mysql
    env_file: ./db/.env

  pma:
    image: "phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin:latest"
    env_file: ./db/.env
    networks:
      web:
    links:
      - db
    ports:
      - "8081:80"

networks:
  web:

volumes: 
  db:
```

*This configuration does not work by the way. I'm in the process of learning docker swarm and its configuration.*

Comment: Have you build an image using Dockerfile or directly pull from docker hub?

Comment: Directly from docker hub

Comment: Please post your docker-compose file full content.

Comment: Check this : https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/31574

Comment: I have read through that thread and I do get that part where docker resolves the digest of the image and tries to use the exact same image to spawn services, however it does not explain why the size would vary. Perhaps I'm missing out on something?