# YAML file pulling image but without tag (<none> tag)

Tags: docker, yaml, swarm

I have a YAML file which creates services by pulling images from repository as follows :-

```yaml
services:
  receiver:
    image: 10.170.112.11:5000/receiver:1.0.0
    user: "20001"
    ports:
      - "36200:36200"
    deploy:
      replicas: 3
      restart_policy:
        condition: any
    command: "npm run production"
```

Everything goes well. Service goes up and I can also see image pulled on the server by this yaml but image do not get pulled with tags. I want images to be pulled and cached with tags. What should be done?

```
[DSAD ~]$ docker images

REPOSITORY                     TAG                 IMAGE ID            CREATED             SIZE
10.170.112.11:5000/processor   <none>              e635f9c55e5d        2 hours ago         186MB
10.170.112.11:5000/enricher    <none>              940136867981        6 days ago          276MB
10.170.112.11:5000/receiver    <none>              c33e914cd0bf        7 days ago          153MB
```

Comment: check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50152854/docker-swarm-docker-stack-deploy-results-on-untagged-images-none

Comment: @WishwaPerera 
The reason is given why there's no tag information available but no workaround is given to achieve.